# I Can connect Mac OS Lion to Win 7 via cable but not via wireless...help!

Tags: macbook-pro, network

I have a macbook pro, and netgear n600 modem/router (DGND3700) and a win7 PC that is working nicely with homegroup networking.

when I plug the macbook into the router via a network cable I can 'connect to server...' and get the the win7 shares just fine. but when I try whilst using wireless it refuses to connect.

What should I tweak to make it work? I assume its a problem with the mac because other non-mac computers can see the shares on my win7 box just fine via wireless.

Comment: can you Ping or traceroute the windows machine from the Mac when the Mac is attached to Wifi?

Comment: no...I just get a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i connect on a 2.6Ghz range rather than 5Ghz it works. so its probably that the netgear router (or the macbook) is not supporting ipv6 properly on the 5Ghz range.

Comment: I doubt it's IPV6 related, more than likely a routing or Wifi-to-LAN protection set up on that interface.  If none of the Windows machines are using the 5Ghz interface, I'd compare the settings and see what is different.

Comment: As it happens the windows laptop isn't connecting on 5Ghz so there must be something different in the config on the router between 2.4 and 5